synology NAS active backup for M365 - export log via script
I wrote a script to download the log in Synology NAS active backup for M365. Manually if I click on export everything works. But I need to download it with the script.
The authentication on the NAS is OK, I debugged it. The file downloads but there is an error message inside the code: {"error":{"code":101},"success":false}
I'm stuck, I'm attaching the code, does anyone have any experience with this? It must be possible to download it automatically using a script.
Thank you very much for your help and any advice. Code written in python

https://pastebin.com/EU1RbCQM

import requests
import urllib3
 
# Suppress InsecureRequestWarning
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
 
def get_json(url):
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    return response.json()
 
def download_file(url, sid, file_path):
    headers = {'Cookie': f'id={sid}'}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f"File successfully downloaded to: {file_path}")
    else:
        print("Failed to download the file.")
 
def main():
    host = "xxx"
    user = "xxx"
    password = "xxx."
 
    # Login and obtain session ID
    login_url = f"https://{host}/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=login&version=3&account={user}&passwd={password}&session=FileStation&format=sid"
    login_response = get_json(login_url)
 
    print(f"Login response: {login_response}")
 
    if "data" in login_response and "sid" in login_response["data"]:
        sid = login_response["data"]["sid"]
        print(f"Login successful. Session ID: {sid}")
 
        # URL to download the file
        download_url = f"https://{host}/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.ActiveBackupOffice365&method=download_file&version=1&SynoHash=bWP_dbnWIHl-lmFtCp1qNIvpoRwSrA.NzI&SynoToken=.vLMwHcu.wwuE"
        file_path = "C:\\scripts\\ActiveBackup_Activity_Log.csv"
 
        # Download the file
        download_file(download_url, sid, file_path)
 
        # Logout
        logout_url = f"https://{host}/webapi/auth.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Auth&method=logout&version=3&session=FileStation&_sid={sid}"
        logout_response = get_json(logout_url)
        if logout_response["success"]:
            print("Logout successful.")
        else:
            print("Logout failed.")
    else:
        print("Login failed. Check the username, password, or API endpoints.")
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

